# Odd behaviour when extending an object with a module in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

If I do the following:

```
user = User.new
user.extend Customer
user.is_a? Customer == true
```

it works fine.

However if I do the following (where Profile is a mongoid model and user is embedded):

```
profile = Profile.all.first
profile.user.extend Customer
profile.user.is_a? Customer == false
```

user is no longer a customer. There must be a simple reason for this but I can't see it.

Edit: User and Profile are mongoid Models, ie. profile.user.class = User and profile.class = Profile.

Comment: What is `user.class` and what is `user.class.ancestors`? You still have not provided a complete, reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually ended up being a bug in Mongoid.  Here is the issue with description:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1933

It is now fixed in the latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: every time you call `profile.user` you are getting a new object. Try:

```
2.times{ p profiler.user.object_id }
```

and see what happens. Then try:

```
u = profile.user
u.extend Customer
p u.is_a? Customer
p profile.user.is_a? Customer
```

and see what output you get.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but it actually gives the same object id.

Comment: So if you do `u=profile.user; u.extend Customer; p [u.class, u.class.ancestors]` what do you see?

Comment: for u.class I get User
for u.class.ancestors I get a bunch of Mongoid related classes and modules, as well as Module:0x007fb1fb2cc3d8.